# Video player no longer shows up embeded inline on the wall. Opens up new window instead. Has something changes with Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

At about 11am central this morning, the video player app I work on stopped getting the play button thumbnail that allowed it to be played inline on the wall.  Instead it opens up to a new window (defeating the purpose of it being an inline app).  All my OG tags seem to be in place and I've noticed some other players that used to show up embedded from other sites aren't working either.  Has something changed?

Answer (score 1):

there is an [issue on Facebook about it.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598397860207749)

I saw some video sharing working today, but from pages that don't pass the open graph object debugger

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem - I suspects Facebook changed something in the OG video parser.  A couple video links used to work now no longer viewable on the Facebook wall.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here but for some unexplainable reason it appears to work in IE 11...

Comment: If I override the Chrome user agent to make Facebook think I'm a IE11 browser, the embedded players works well. So it's not that IE11 parses the page properly, is Facebook sending the correct page version in IE11...